# Return an object to its original rotation and height unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

I want to allow a boat in my 3D simulation of a ship to rotate and be moved on all axes. However, the way that I have the boat's movement programmed makes this impossible.

The way it moves:

```
this.transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.smoothDeltaTime * speed);
```

The way it turns:

```
this.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * Time.smoothDeltaTime * (int)horizontal)
```

The shape of the boat also makes it impossible to simply move it on  a solid base, since it does have the triangular shape (for underwater collisions).

So what I want to do is allow the boat to be affected by gravity, but still float on the water. Then, when the boat hits something, it needs to be able to "roll" and then eventually return to its normal position.

So, is there any way to make an object slowly return to its normal rotation(z rotation of 0) after it hit something, and not be affected by gravity once it reaches a certain elevation. (Y value of 34.75)

The boat has a **Rigidbody** and a **Mesh Collider**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if the player would be able to move when he gets hit, but you could save the current values to local variables (for example: `Transform transformOnHit`). After you complete the roll, you can use your own provided code to translate and rotate back to the original transform.